dbt copy_partitions with job parallelization in Bigquery
I am creating dbt models with copy_partitions=true, but the problem is when I need to ingest a number of partitions with a large volume of data, the whole process can take a long time as dbt iterates by calling the Bigquery API for each partition. Is there a way to parallelize those copy_partitions jobs in dbt?
I tried Thread configuration but does not work, since threads parallelize models executions and not API calls.

Hi,
dbt-bigquery uses copy_bq_table function to invoke bq copy command. It has already supported parallel execution (see the comment at the beginning of the function).
The problem is that this macro supports invoking copy_bq_table only one partition at a time.

It might be good if you can open a discussion in the repository about this topic.

Thanks @KlimentMerzlyakov I've opened the discussion https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/discussions/1236

Thank you! Apologies, turns out that discussions are for big ideas, and this one is more like a feature request.
I've created a feature request for it: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/issues/1237
